# Find row and column index of top values in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

The position (row and column) of the maximum value in a matrix can be found by:

```
ma <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 5)
which(ma == max(ma), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

What if we do not want just the coordinates of the maximum but those of the N highest values?

Something like:

```
order(ma, arr.ind = TRUE, decreasing = TRUE)[1:N] # this does not exist :(
```

Comment: you can use eg N=5:
lapply(sort(ma,decreasing = T)[1:5],function(x)which(ma == x, arr.ind = TRUE))

Comment: A more terse and efficient solution than the answer below is: [List (and plot) top k values of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264488/4891738).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ma <- matrix(1:50, nrow=5)

# find the 5 largest values
x <- which(ma>=sort(ma, decreasing = T)[5], arr.ind = T)
# determine the order of the 5 largest values in decreasing order
x.order <- order(ma[x], decreasing = T)
x[x.order, ]
#      row col
# [1,]   5  10
# [2,]   4  10
# [3,]   3  10
# [4,]   2  10
# [5,]   1  10
```